# How does memory_order_seq_cst synchronize with non-atomic operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

If one uses a single atomic variable and `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, are non-atomic operations guaranteed not to be reordered?

For example, if I have

```
std::atomic<bool> quux = {false};

void foo() {
    bar();
    quux.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    moo();
}
```

is `bar()` guaranteed not to get reordered after the call of `store`, and `moo()` not to get reordered before the call of `store`, as long as I use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, at least from the perspective of another thread?

Or, to put it in code, are the following assumptions valid if run from another thread?

```
if(quux.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) == true) {
   // bar guaranteed to be called; its side-effects are visible
   // moo might have been called, but is not guaranteed to
} else {
   // bar might have been called, but is not guaranteed to
   // moo might have been called, but is not guaranteed to
}
```

Note that I assume that neither `bar` nor `moo` use atomic operations, mutexes, locks, fences or other synchronization features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one uses a single atomic variable and `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, are non-atomic operations guaranteed not to be reordered?

The standard is pretty clear on this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order:

> `memory_order_seq_cst` A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order.
>
> `memory_order_acquire` A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location: **no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load**.
>
> `memory_order_release` A store operation with this memory order performs the release operation: **no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store**.

In other words, no loads or stores (both non-atomic and atomic) can be reordered around `memory_order_seq_cst` operations.

---

> is `bar()` guaranteed not to get reordered after the call of store, and `moo()` not to get reordered before the call of store, as long as I use std::memory_order_seq_cst, at least from the perspective of another thread?

If the definitions of `bar` and `moo` are not available in the current translation unit, the compiler assumes that these functions do memory loads and/or have side effects (do I/O or stores to memory), and hence cannot be reordered around `memory_order_seq_cst` operations.

If the definitions are available and the functions do not do I/O or memory loads/stores then they can be reordered. These would be [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) or functions that do nothing and return `void` or a constant.

Comment: Nitpicking, but: while cppreference.com is superb, it's not the ISO standard.

Comment: @Zeta You are right. I find cppreference.com quite accurate, there may be omissions though, since it is not a copy of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

According to the link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order linked by @Maxim there is an error with regards of the memory_order_seq_cst.The text above is exchanged with memory_order_acq_rel. The text for memory_order_seq_cst:

memory_order_seq_cst: A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order (see Sequentially-consistent ordering below)

So in your case the store operation is equivalent to a release which means that moo() can be reordered before the fence.

Comment: I updated `memory_order_seq_cst` with an up-to-date description, and it appears to me that only the 1st sentence was _elaborated_. IMO, your claim about "exchanged text" isn't right.

Answer (score -2):

Because the strictest memory order is used, the functions bar and moo cannot be reordered past or before the store to quux respectively.

Your conclusion for the if-else case is not quite correct.

If the expression `if(quux.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) == true)` evaluates to true, then the function bar will definitely already complete its call. The order of call to moo cannot be determined. It might have finished, not started or it could be in the middle of the call.

If the mentioned expression evaluates to false, then we cannot determine order for both functions. While it is true that at the moment the expression evaluates to false, the function moo hasn't been called yet, it might be called just after that, before the execution proceed to the else clause. Once in the else clause, the status of the function moo is the same as in the previous paragraph (it cannot be determined).